# How can I get my local service URL?

Tags: arccatalog, map-service

I created a local map service in ArcCatalog.

Then I opened ArcCatalog and in "GIS Servers" clicked in XXX (my computer name). Then listed services down. I right clicked on my service and select services properties. Then I clicked on capabilies. There is a URL TextBox.

Is this my service URL?

If yes: Why This URL not work in browser?

If no: How can I get the service URL?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? For your description, if you connect to your "GIS Server" > list services > right click on your service > Service Properties > Capabilities > Mapping, yes, that is your REST endpoint for your service. If you copy this link into your server, you should see a text web page describing your service. What do you see in your screen?

Comment: Hi
Thanks for response.
I copy this 
http://mehdi-pc/arcgis/services/HasanAbad/MapServer/
and see this
Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE"

Comment: I think you are missing, at least, the port number. In ArcGIS 10.1 is 6080 and, if I am not wrong, in 10.0 is 8399. Could you try this URL in your browser: "localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services" and see if you can access the root folder of your ArcGIS REST Services Directory? From there you can browse to "/HasanAbad/Mapserver". If still it is not working, could be that you do not have enabled/installed in your IIS server ASP.NET?

Comment: :( :( I check all of them. but these isn't work in my computer :( I edit permission on C:\arcgisserver\arcgisoutput\HasanAbad_MapServer and access to Everyone (!!!) full control and try http://localhost:8399/arcgis/services/HasanAbad/MapServer. but both of them raised error : could not connect to localhost:8399

Comment: i am useing arcgis 10

Comment: I think all the pieces you need are here in the comments - first try http://mehdi-pc/arcgis/rest/services I don't remember ArcGIS 10 using port 8399 - mine defaulted to 80 through IIS default website

Answer (score 1):

An OGC web service (OWS) end point (service URL) is the the URL you give to client, such as ArcMap, OpenLayers, QGIS etc. to which the client will add parameters to make a valid request.

An OWS endpoint on its own does not give any content, and browsing to it will often give an error, depending on how the service has been configured.

Consider the following public WMS service:

http://services.azgs.az.gov/arcgis/services/OneGeology/AZGS_Arizona_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?

Browsing this URL, results in an error.

What your client (or you) need to add parameters to the URL to get content, for example the capabilities of the service would be (adding parameters `service=WMS&` to define the service type and `request=GetCapabilities&` to define the operation):

http://services.azgs.az.gov/arcgis/services/OneGeology/AZGS_Arizona_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&

and to get a map image you might make the following GetMap request:

http://services.azgs.az.gov/arcgis/services/OneGeology/AZGS_Arizona_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?LAYERS=US-AZ_AZGS_1M_Geologic_Age&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE&FORMAT=image/png&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=32.0514611520822,-116.3832185371762,36.19224571134423,-105.77670071119765&WIDTH=1250&HEIGHT=488&